# how to re-enable input on a serial console

Tags: linux, embedded, tty, serial-console, serial-port

I have an old router which runs Linux and I'd like to have a serial console on.  This used to work fine, but after a firmware update, I can now only get output on the console and cannot give any input back to the device.  During boot there is a line that says "Console input is disabled" that wasn't there before.

Without changing the firmware, how do I re-enable input on the serial console?

... my attempts so far ...

I can log in over the LAN and load any files (and cross compile tools if need be), and there is a small non-volatile user flash partition, so any solution requiring me to write a quick program using ioctl or whatnot is fine.  The embedded Linux has the system files like `/sys/bus` and `/sys/devices/platform/serial8250.0` and so on in case that is useful.  The files `/dev/console`, `/dev/ttyS0`, `/dev/tty` all have read and write permissions. Running `getty -L 115200 ttyS0` makes a login prompt appear on the serial console, but I can't get it to accept any input.  Adding the line

```
::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

to `inittab` makes busybox give a shell prompt ... but again, the serial console won't take input.

dmesg reports

```
Kernel command line: root=/dev/ram rw init=/init console=ttyS0,115200
```

and `stty` gives

```
speed 38400 baud; line=0;
```

along with a bunch of unimportant looking settings,
`stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0` gives

```
speed 115200 baud; stty: /dev/ttyS0  
line = 0;
```

(and a whole bunch of settings that don't look important, but I'll type them up if people need them.)

I'm at a loss here, so I'm not sure what information is needed.
Any ideas for solving this puzzle?  I have a feeling there is something simple I forgot to try.

Comment: So this is special-purpose hardware that runs Linux as its firmware?  They may have changed a hardware setting to prevent reading the input.  Would a `stty -a` (lists all stty settings) give us more clues?  Perhaps the kernel boot string specifies some different options now?

Answer (score 2):

[The busybox example `inittab`](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/examples/inittab) looks a little different,

```
# Example of how to put a getty on a serial line (for a terminal)
#
#::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 9600 vt100
#::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS1 9600 vt100
```

could you give this a try?

Comment: Same as before, it makes a login prompt appear on the serial console, but I can't give it any input.  I need to somehow enable input on /dev/console or something.

Comment: If you use kernel param `console=ttyS0,11520`, try to change speed in /etc/inittab from `9600` to `115200`.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a very old post, but I recall having seen some similar problem after updating a Samsung TV. Probably the router model you have, belong to some company who doesn't allow external modifications like OpenWRT etc. For example, a common way to disable terminal shell access is to disable it in the kernel sources `/linux-2.6.35.11/drivers/char/n_tty.c` or compile kernel with: `CONFIG_SERIAL_INPUT_DISABLE_STRING`...